# How to make a closable banner in pure javascript

Tags: javascript, css, banner

I want to make a closeable banner like this one at the top:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2m9U.jpg

using only html, css, and javascript

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. please show codes of what you have tried. we are not here to do eachotehrs' home work. we can help in errors or problems you have faced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this bootstrap example: http://www.bootply.com/91822

Or this fiddle I just quickly put together: http://jsfiddle.net/foxu9o9d/
the JS goes along the lines of:

```
var btn = document.querySelector('#btn-dismiss');

btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
    var alert = document.querySelector('#fixed-alert');
    alert.style.display = 'none';
});
```

Comment: is this pure javascript?!! if yes is it new? is this supported in regular browsers?

Comment: it is pure JS. It's supported in these browsers (IE8+, etc): http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector ; addEventListener is supported in all major browsers and IE9+;

Comment: +1 and thanks. i knew that one day such queries will be added to javascript lol.

Comment: didn't work for me in safari in 2021